# dynamic control values

Tags: master-pages

How to get the text of the dynamical textbox which is added to the dynamical table ,which is added to the panel on the form, that form is having the masterpage?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your talking about ASP.NET? Are you trying to get the value in the code behind or client side using Javascript?

If its server side, and your `<asp:Panel>` is declared on the page, you could do...

```
foreach(Control c in myPanel.Controls)
{
    if(c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
        if(tb.ID == "The ID Your Looking For")
        {
           //Do stuff with tb.Text;
        }
    }
}
```